# how search a word in each row of my dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I wanna search a string in my dataframe. But I keep getting error.

Each row of my data frame is something like the following:

```
["CRM, Product, Merchandising, Pricing & Planning Manager -LA MER EMEA (100M$NS) - CDI", "Promotions& Fragrance Manager CLINIQUE EMEA (500M$ NS)-CDI", "Sales representative in flagship doors", "Marketing Manager Latin America/ Indies/Caribbean (V.I.E ) Guerlain - Miami (20M$ NS)", "Product Manager L’Oréal Paris, Men Expert, Roger & Gallet (trainee) DPGP TR EMEA", "Business Analyst Biotherm&Helena Rubinstein (trainee) DPL EMEA", "Product Development Manager (trainee) International Marketing", "Sales woman in flagship doors -Guerlain", "Trade Marketing Manager Latin America/ Indies/Caribbean (V.I.E ) Guerlain - Miami (18M$ NS)", "Beauty Brand Manager", "CRM, Product, Merchandising, Pricing & Planning Manager -LA MER EMEA (100M$NS) - CDI", "Promotions& Fragrance Manager CLINIQUE EMEA (500M$ NS)-CDI", "Sales representative in flagship doors", "Trade Marketing Manager Latin America/ Indies/Caribbean (V.I.E ) Guerlain - Miami (18M$ NS)", "Product Manager L’Oréal Paris, Men Expert, Roger & Gallet (trainee) DPGP TR EMEA", "Business Analyst Biotherm&Helena Rubinstein (trainee) DPL EMEA", "Product Development Manager (trainee) International Marketing", "Sales woman in flagship doors -Guerlain", "Beauty Brand Manager", "CRM, Product, Merchandising, Pricing & Planning Manager -LA MER EMEA (100M$NS) - CDI", "Promotions& Fragrance Manager CLINIQUE EMEA (500M$ NS)-CDI", "Sales representative in flagship doors", "Trade Marketing Manager Latin America/ Indies/Caribbean (V.I.E ) Guerlain - Miami (18M$ NS)", "Product Manager L’Oréal Paris, Men Expert, Roger & Gallet (trainee) DPGP TR EMEA", "Business Analyst Biotherm&Helena Rubinstein (trainee) DPL EMEA", "Product Development Manager (trainee) International Marketing", "Sales woman in flagship doors -Guerlain", "Senior Beauty Brand Manager",]
```

I wanna filter all row contained the word `intern`:

I used the following code:

`data_select.filter(col("title").contains('intern,'))`
But I get the following error:

`AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'contains(`title`, 'intern,')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`title`' is of array<string> type.;`

Comment: `contains` is for String column. However, your `title` is array of string, so you need to use `array_contains`. 
 https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html

Comment: I tried this: `data_select.select(array_contains(data_select.title, "intern,")).collect()` but I got error : `NameError: name 'array_contains' is not defined`

Comment: sorry, I misspoke. `array_contains` will do full match within the array. Although, you are looking for a function to have a sub-match within the element.  I will write an option in answer.

Answer (score 1):

since you are matching with the substring in the array, one way to do it without changing schema is to cast the array of string into string to use `rlike`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.filter(F.col('title').cast(StringType()).rlike('.*intern.*'))
df.show()  # use show instead of collect. "collect" will collect all data into a single driver node. (cost heavy operation)
```